# Learning Object Detection Detected result showed in discolouration

Tags: python, colors, pytorch, object-detection, yolov5

**Breif Description**

Recently begin to learning Object Detection, Just starting off with PyTorch, YOLOv5. So I thought why not build a small side project to learn? Using it to train to detect Pikachu.

**The Problem**

I've successfully trained the model with Pikachu and then uses trained weights with myself written Python script/code to detect the Pikachu using test images, now, here's the problem, Pikachus can successfully detected but **all the result showed in blue discolouration, what supposed to be yellow, all turned into blue and blue into yellow**.

[Fig-1 Result images showed in blue discolouration(few example outputs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSetd.jpg)

**Additional Imformation**

I've pushed this project to the GitHub, feel free to download it or pull it to debugging.

[GitHub repository where it contains all the files](https://git.io/J0FAQ)

Any solution/suggestion would be helpful, Thanks.

**The Code**

```py
"""Object detection using YOLOv5

Pokemon Pikachu detecting

"""

# import os, sys to append YOLOv5 folder path
import os, sys

# import object detection needed modules and libraries
# pillow
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import numpy as np
import torch # PyTorch


# YOLOv5 folder path and related folder path settings
cwd = os.getcwd()
root_dir = (cwd + "/yolov5_stable")
sys.path.append(root_dir)


# import methods, functions from YOLOv5
from models.experimental import attempt_load
from utils.datasets import LoadImages
from utils.general import non_max_suppression, scale_coords
from utils.plots import colors



# define a function to show detected pikachu
def show_pikachu(img, det):
    labels = ["pikachu"]
    img = Image.fromarray(img)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font_size = max(round(max(img.size)/40), 12)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(cwd + "/yolov5_stable/fonts/times.ttf")

    for info in det:
        color = colors(1)
        target, prob = int(info[5].cpu().numpy()), np.round(info[4].cpu().numpy(), 2)
        x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3]
        draw.rectangle([x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max], width = 3, outline = color)
        draw.text((x_min, y_min), labels[target] + ':' + str(prob), fill = color, font = font)

    # Bug unresolved, pikachu shown in blue discolouration

    return img


if __name__ == "__main__":
    device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    print("GPU State: ", device)
    
    data_path = (cwd + "/test_data/")
    weight_path = (cwd + "/yolov5_stable/weights/best_v1.pt")
    dataset = LoadImages(data_path)
    model = attempt_load(weight_path, map_location = device)
    model.to(device)
    
    for path, img, im0s, _ in dataset:
        img = torch.from_numpy(img).to(device)
        img = img.float() # uint8 to fp16/32
        img /= 255.0 # 0-255 to 0.0-1.0
        if img.ndimension() == 3:
            img = img.unsqueeze(0)
            
        pred = model(img)[0]
        pred = non_max_suppression(pred, 0.25, 0.45)
        for i, det in enumerate(pred):
            im0 = im0s.copy()
            det[:, :4] = scale_coords(img.shape[2:], det[:, :4], im0.shape).round()
            result = show_pikachu(im0, det)
            result.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Image.fromarray` expects image in RGB and you're providing them in BGR. You just need to change that. There are multiple places you could do that, for instance:

```py
Image.fromarray(img[...,::-1])  # assuming `img` is channel-last
```

An evidence is that the red parts of the mouse (red is `RGB(255, 0, 0)`) are being shown in blue (which is `RGB(0, 0, 255)`). FYI, yellow is `RGB(255, 255, 0)` and cyan is `RGB(0, 255, 255)`, which you can also see in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot believe that I missed that when I went through Pillow documentation. I initially thought and focused on `ImageDraw` and `Color` and thought maybe I missed an import of `ImageColor`.